# Getting "socket.timeout: The read operation timed out" while applying translation on huge file using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, google-translation-api

I am using google_trans_new to translate in English. I've a panda dataframe and it has more than 1000 rows. When I'm applying translation logic it throws "socket.timeout: The read operation timed out" error.
In my code I've defined socket.setdefaulttimeout and also split the dataframe by 100 rows in each split but still I'm encountering the same error.

Sample dataframe

[image]

Code:

```
from google_trans_new import google_translator
import socket
import numpy as np

socket.setdefaulttimeout(900)

exl_file = 'ipfile.xlsx'
df = pd.read_excel(exl_file)

translator = google_translator()

splitSize = 100
for g, df in df.groupby(np.arange(len(df)) // splitSize):
    print(df.shape)
    df['trans_val'] = df['value'].apply(lambda x: translator.translate(x, lang_tgt='en'))
```

Error:

**socket.timeout: _ssl.c:761: The handshake operation timed out**

Can you please suggest if there is any better approach to apply translation logic on huge file?

Comment: use `try/except` to catch error

Comment: it seems this module simply scrape data from web page - so Google may block it as a spamer/hacker. You should try to use official method - with Google API - but this meed more work. It needs to register your script in Google to get `client_id`, `client_secret`  (to access API) and later it needs to generate `token` to access data. You should start with [google-cloud-translate](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/reference/libraries/v2/python)